# AS3 how to access movieclip from a child added in runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I created a child that will be added on runtime. How do I access a movieclip on the mainstage from within the child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice would be to pass a reference to the already on stage clip, in to the child, from the container of both

```
this.myAddedClip.otherStageClip = this.alreadyOnStageClip;
```

This avoids hardcoding structural information into a child instance, which is an object oriented no-no, and usually leads to spaghetti code.

As a rule of thumb objects should usually only "know" about their direct children.

As you can see from this example the child object still ends up with a reference to the other one, but it doesn't need to know that it was already on the stage, or who its parent object is etc.